# ArrayList to JList and display specific property of the objects

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I would like to know if there is a way to display a specific property for the items  of a `JList` when it is built from an `ArrayList`.

I just want to choose the property that will be displayed in a list when I do this:

```
JList<String> elementsList = new JList(elementsArrayList.toArray());
elementsScrollPane.setViewportView(elementsList);
```

Thanks for any help or references you could give me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a [`ListCellRenderer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ListCellRenderer.html).

Essentially, you write a function

```
public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list,
    Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus)
```

which returns a `Component`. To make things easier, you can extend [`DefaultListCellRenderer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListCellRenderer.html) and call it's implementation after you extracted the value you want to display from the list element, ie

```
{
    if (value instanceof YourClass) {
        YourClass ob = (YourClass) value;
        return super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, ob.getProperty(), index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
    }
    return super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
}
```

Then you [set your renderer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#setCellRenderer(javax.swing.ListCellRenderer)) to your `elementList`.

Comment: Thank you @daniu! Finally I've created a class which extends DefaultListCellRenderer and I've overriden the ´getListCellRendererComponent()´ function. After I've setted the cellRenderer of the list with this new class. I've used the cellRenderers before but I forgot to use it to this!

Answer (score 1):

1.

The simplest way is

first to scan your input elements list for the property you desire to show

```
String[] properties = elementsArrayList.stream().map(element::getStringProperty).toArray()
```

Then use it as an input model for your swing control
   new JList(properties)

2. The canonical, Swing-like one is

define JList basing on the original objects you have (through ListModer or as is, by an array)

```
new JList(elementsArrayList)
```

and then create your ListCellRenderer class, which will display the property of interest as a lable and set this renderer to the list

```
jList.setCellRenderer(youCellRedererInstance)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Did it by using the cellRenderer!